# Wordpress : Redirect Page after sign up failed - Essential Addons for Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i have created a signup page on wordpress with elementor and using "Essential Addons for Elementor" plugin . After i have triggered register button, instead of going to home page. it was redirected back to my signup page.  i have check the option on the plugin settings but to redirect to home page after register button is triggered is no where to found , e.g image below is showing login form to redirect page after login option but not register button

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i have check and found out that within my snippets plugin , i could add redirect php function to overwrite the function. i have added below code but failed, it was redirected back to my register page instead of my homepage e.g using [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as demo purpose only

```
add_filter("woocommerce_registration_redirect", "wcs_register_redirect");
function wcs_register_redirect($redirect) {
  $redirect = "www.google.com";
  return $redirect;
}
```

Need some advices on this

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the filter you're using, you can try increasing the priority so it'll be the last to be called, and so the last to return a value:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_registration_redirect", "wcs_register_redirect", 200, 1);
function wcs_register_redirect($redirect) {
  $redirect = "www.google.com";
  return $redirect;
}
```

Also, you use `return get_home_url();` to get your homepage URL.